# KDE exibition glitch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde-plasma

My KDE is broken, the desktop Widgets cannot be displayed. And many KDE programs look like this:

[image]

All the software written in GTK is all right.

Can any one give me any suggestion about what's happening and which part is broken?

Where can I find error log?

Comment: What version of KDE? What GPU hardware? You might want to try pressing Alt-Shift-F12 to disable desktop effects and see if that fixes things up.

Comment: @parry it's KDE 4.10.5, my GPU is DH6670, it still not works when desktop effects are disabled.

Comment: OK. What kernel version (uname -a) are you running and have you installed the binary ATI Catalyst driver or are you using the default Open Source Radeon Driver?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what disto you're using (please add it to the tags in your question), nor how you got in this state - new installation? dist-upgrade? hard crash? That would be useful information.

But in general, here's what I would try:
Log out and go to a bare terminal with `CTRL-ALT-F1`, then login and rename your .kde / .kde4 directories: `mv ~/.kde ~/.kde.old` and reboot or otherwise restart your GUI system.
That will at least tell you whether the problem is messed up personal settings or messed-up system files.

If that doesn't fix the issue (that directory will be recreated when you start up KDE again; all your settings will be lost, but you can recover them - carefully, one by one - from the backup you just made), then I would first try `sudo apt-get check` (assuming you're on a Debian-based distro).
If that doesn't report any problems, then I would update my system - possibly even do a dist-upgrade without changes any sources.
If this issue still wasn't fixed, I would run `sudo dpkg -l > ~/Desktop/dpkg_out.txt` to get a list of installed or uninstalled packages and their state in a file, and then look through the file for problems as explained [here](http://blog.onetechnical.com/2007/10/04/apt-get-package-status-codes/).
Finally, if all of that failed, I would take a good hard look at my video drivers.
Good luck!